# SSL issues on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

I have a code in Python that accepts (E)SMTP requests via aiosmtp but since I pushed this code on Debian 10, I'm having a few errors that wasn't present before (and my code didn't changed):

**[SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:1056)**

> SSL handshake failed
>   protocol: 
>   transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=11 read=polling write=>

```
SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:1056)
  File "asyncio/sslproto.py", line 625, in _on_handshake_complete
    raise handshake_exc
  File "asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

and:

**[SSL: KRB5_S_INIT] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2609)**

> SSL error in data received
>   protocol: 
>   transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=15 read=polling write=>

```
SSLError: [SSL: KRB5_S_INIT] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2609)
  File "asyncio/sslproto.py", line 526, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "asyncio/sslproto.py", line 207, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.unwrap()
  File "ssl.py", line 767, in unwrap
    return self._sslobj.shutdown()
```

I think these two issues are related.

Unfortunately the two stacktrace don't show anything related to my code, which makes it harder for me to better see where this is happening, and the exception isn't related to another exception (Python3).

---

Here's the versions of my package:

uname -a : `Linux my-server 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-5+deb10u2 (2019-08-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

python --version: `Python 3.7.3`

**pip freeze**

```
aiomysql==0.0.20
aiosmtpd==1.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
atpublic==1.0
authres==1.2.0
beanstalkc3==0.4.0
blinker==1.4
certifi==2018.8.24
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cloud-init==18.3
configobj==5.0.6
cryptography==2.6.1
distro-info==0.21
dkimpy==0.9.4
dnspython==1.16.0
fail2ban==0.10.2
Flask==1.1.1
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
jsonpatch==1.21
jsonpointer==1.10
jsonschema==2.6.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
mysqlclient==1.4.4
oauthlib==2.1.0
psutil==5.6.3
py3dns==3.2.1
pycparser==2.19
PyGObject==3.30.4
pyinotify==0.9.6
PyJWT==1.7.0
PyMySQL==0.9.2
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pyspf==2.0.13
pysrs==1.0.3
python-apt==1.8.4
python-dotenv==0.10.3
PyYAML==3.13
requests==2.21.0
sentry-sdk==0.12.3
six==1.12.0
systemd-python==234
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.24.1
uWSGI==2.0.18
Werkzeug==0.16.0
```

---

I believe that if something was wrong with my code, I would have had this error on Debian 9 and earlier which I never had.

I searched on SO and Google about this error but didn't find anything. I suspect some issue on a specific version of a specific project (aiosmtpd, async or python) but don't have any clue.

I'm hoping you'll be able to help me :)

---

Update:

I've added tracking of ciphers in the communication. The shared ciphers are:

```
[[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLSv1.3, 256], [TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLSv1.3, 256], [TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLSv1.3, 128], [ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, TLSv1.2, 256], [ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, TLSv1.2, 256], [DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, TLSv1.2, 256], [ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305, TLSv1.2, 256], [ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305, TLSv1.2, 256], [DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305, TLSv1.2, 256], [ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, TLSv1.2, 128], [ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, TLSv1.2, 128]]
```

And the Cipher for the socket is: `[ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, TLSv1.2, 256]` which is in the shared ciphers.

---

Update 2

I can reproduce the error, but only under specific conditions.

On the new server, here's the code I run:

```
import asyncio, logging, sys, signal, ssl
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller
from aiosmtpd.handlers import Debugging
from aiosmtpd.smtp import SMTP

class ControllerTls(Controller):
    def factory(self):
        context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
        context.load_cert_chain('./certs/certificate.pem', './certs/id_rsa')
        context.load_dh_params('./certs/dhparams.pem')
        return SMTP(
            self.handler,
            tls_context=context
        )


# Temporary outputing errors from mail.log
streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
streamHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)-15s] (%(levelname)s) - %(message)s'))
streamHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

maillog = logging.getLogger('mail.log')
maillog.setLevel(logging.INFO)
maillog.addHandler(streamHandler)

controller = ControllerTls(Debugging(), hostname='0.0.0.0', port=2125)
controller.start()
print('Controller started!')
sig = signal.sigwait([signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGQUIT])
controller.stop()
```

It's a basic script that helps me reproduce the issue.

On the Old server, I run this code:

```
import smtplib, ssl, sys

port = 25
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    port = sys.argv[2]

def com(client, command, *args, **kwargs):
    result = getattr(client, command)(*args, **kwargs)
    if result[0] > 500:
        print('[FATAL] - An error occured!')
        print(result)
        client.quit()
        exit()

context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain('/var/www/towboat/certs/certificate.pem', '/var/www/towboat/certs/id_rsa')
context.set_ciphers('ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384')
client = smtplib.SMTP(sys.argv[1], port=port)
com(client, 'ehlo')
com(client, 'starttls', context=context)
com(client, 'ehlo')
com(client, 'mail', 'contact@improvmx.com')
com(client, 'rcpt', 'cyril@improvmx.com')
com(client, 'quit')

print('All good !')
```

Which I call with :

`sendmail.py {ip.of.new.server} 2125`

On the old server (the one running the script), I get this error:

```
Controller started!
[2019-10-08 15:57:11,878] (INFO) - Peer: ('ip.of.old.server', 45492)
[2019-10-08 15:57:11,878] (INFO) - ('ip.of.old.server', 45492) handling connection
[2019-10-08 15:57:11,880] (INFO) - ('ip.of.old.server', 45492) Data: b'ehlo {name old server}'
[2019-10-08 15:57:11,883] (INFO) - ('ip.of.old.server', 45492) Data: b'STARTTLS'
[2019-10-08 15:57:11,883] (INFO) - ('ip.of.old.server', 45492) STARTTLS
SSL handshake failed
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7f04d33d7d30>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=7 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 625, in _on_handshake_complete
    raise handshake_exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:1056)
SSL error in data received
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7f04d33d7d30>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport closing fd=7 read=idle write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 526, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:1056)
[2019-10-08 15:58:33,909] (INFO) - Connection lost during _handle_client()
```

What's super odd, is that if I copy the sendmail script on my local machine, and run it pointing to the new server, I don't have the error anymore!

(So the issue must be related to the old server? But why the new server shows the exception?!)

If I switch the scripts (testing sending an email from the new server to the old), it works...

Comment: There are too much unknowns for me in this question, specifically there is no code for the server and there are no information about the client. It could for example be that the client uses some old and insecure cipher like RC4 or 3DES which are disabled in newer versions of Debian. Or it could be that the server explicitly tries to set such ciphers. It could also be that the server certificates are not properly installed in which case no useful ciphers are available. See also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There are too much unknowns for me too, that's why I've opened a question here, hoping to have some ideas to pinpoint the origin of the issue. I don't even know where in my code this is happening. I have two servers where this code is running: one with this error, the other without. Can I compare the cipher enabled on both? Or if the certificates where properly installed? any idea how?

Comment: For a start, investigate which precise SSL/TLS versions the remote clients support.

Comment: @CyrilN.:  The unknowns I've mentioned could actually be addressed by you in your question since you have the code of the server and know about the client. There is no generic "compare cipher enabled". But you can for example do a packet capture with the same client and the old (working) server to see which cipher gets used (analyze with wireshark) and then check that the same client will not work with the new server.

Comment: @tripleee When you say client, you mean the one connecting to my service? Or my code?

Comment: The remote SMTP client connecting to your service which is attempting to set up an SSL connection. The error means you are offering one set of ciphers and they support another set and there is no common intersection.

Comment: @tripleee I have two servers, one that works and this one. I can compare the version on both. Where can I check that? On OpenSSL ?

Comment: https://noxxi.de/howto/ssl-debugging.html is my first google hit

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm having issues to see how I can address something I can't address ... (the unknown). I'm happy to provide all the details requested to help me out here, and I'm updating the question everytime I can share something new.

Comment: Here's my top google hit for a more direct question about how to show the ciphers supported by a server: https://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers

Comment: @CyrilN.: *"I'm happy to provide all the details requested to help me out here"* - then please provide details about the client (what software, OS, maybe code) and create (and provide the code) a minimal version of your server which is sufficient to reproduce the problem with this client (i.e. works on old Debian, stops working on new).

Comment: @tripleee I've tested a few scripts from the link you shared, they target http server and doesn't work on smtp from what I've saw :/

Comment: `openssl` should be able to connect to anything which tries to speak SSL. Or you could write a simple Python client which connects to the unencrypted connection and then takes you through the `STARTTLS` negotiation.

Comment: @tripleee Yeah I think I'm going to have to do something like that. I tried with sslscan which is very interesting, but it isn't available on Debian10, Too bad because TLSSLed looks very interesting. I'll try to make it work monday. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @CyrilN.: *"... if there is hundreds of them connecting, should I ask each of them by getting the ip back, asking their ISP their phone number and asking them to try again ??"* - Nothing in your question suggests that you have this problem only with a specific client but that you know nothing about this client and that it is out of your control what this client is doing. Again, there is a lack of essential details in your question.

Comment: @CyrilN.: Based on your new information in the comment it looks like that the server is working for the majority of clients but there is only one or a few which have problems. In this case my guess is that these clients are old and  try to use some (weak) RC4 or 3DES based ciphers as was common some years ago.  Because these weak ciphers are no longer enabled in modern TLS stacks (i.e. not enabled in your server) these clients will fail with `no shared cipher`.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Sorry about my last comment. What I mean is that I don't have any way to test from the clients nor target where in the code the issue is occuring. The important point I think will help is that the same code is on two different servers (Debian 9 vs 10 and Python 3.5 vs 3.7, probably a different version of OpenSSL too). I can test the differences between the two servers until I find the culprit, but my question here is about what to test and how as I'm clueless here. (and hopefully find a solution)

Comment: @CyrilN.: as I said these are likely old client trying to use weak ciphers. If you really need to support these you probably need to recompile OpenSSL with support for these weak ciphers and also link Python against it. It might additionally be necessary to explicitly allow these ciphers in your (unknown) code.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the shared cipher on the server and the cipher decided for the socket. I don't know if it helps?

Comment: Maybe silly question, but are you sure there is no certificate verification error? e.g. `SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED`.  To me it looks like issue with the certificate verification process, could you check that?

Comment: @tukan Happy to! How can I do ?

Comment: Checking the logs when you try to connect?

Comment: I've deployed the same code on another Debian 10 installation with Python3.7, and I get the same issue. I've also discovered that I can't connect at all (Starttls command works, then everything else fails). I'm suspecting some problem between my code, Python3.7 and Debian 10. I'm currently installing Python 3.6 on the Debian 10, and installing Debian 9 on another system, to try to narrow the problem.

Comment: Doesn't work with Python 3.5 and Debian 9 neither. I'm goign to compare the packages installed.

Comment: Ok false route, it was caused by something unrelated ... :/

Comment: I've run this script (https://gist.github.com/daybarr/987dddde385ec5e04af3) that should list all the ciphers from Python's SSL implementation. On my old server (that don't throw an exception), I can generate the list. But on the recent server, here's what I get: `!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5:!3DES:!DES:!RC4:!IDEA:!SEED:!aDSS:!SRP:!PSK:!TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:!TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:!TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:!TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:!TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:!TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:!TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` => The cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 gets appended in loop! I don't know why, but this is odd.

Comment: If you try to list it with `openssl ciphers -s -v ECDHE` will it show the complete list?

Comment: I went a quite similar way. I run `openssl ciphers`, copy/pasted the code in a "sendmail" script I built that uses starttls, and made a loop to test all the ciphers on both the working and non working server. Got no error..

Comment: I run the `openssl ciphers` in both the new and old server and also my local computer too!

Comment: Ok, I managed to have a beginning of a working issue. I've written a sendmail script that uses starttls, and the cipher `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`. On my old server that tries to connect to the new: it fails (no shared cipher). The same code on my local machine that connects to the new server: it works! So the difference is between my old server and my local machin

Comment: I've updated the code with a working bug _that works only on my specific server_ ...

Comment: What `openssl` version are you using on the non-working server and what on working one?

Comment: v1.1.1d on the new server, 1.1.0d on the old one.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is the cause:

> v1.1.1d on the new server, 1.1.0d on the old one

The *1.1.1* line introduces the **TLSv3** and many other quite important changes - [see the change log](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x3).

As I have seen you [opening a ticket](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/issues/173) at *aiosmtpd github* you have guessed correctly that the reason why you are getting the error is the aiosmtpd.  The reason being there is it supports *You need at least Python 3.5*, which has **no** support for *openssl 1.1.1*.  Only [python 3.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue32947) (it has not been fully backported even to *python 3.6*) currently supports *openssl 1.1.1*.

Since the latest version of *aiosmtpd* is [**1.2 (2018-09-01)**](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/blob/97730f37f4a283b3da3fa3dbf30dd925695fea69/aiosmtpd/docs/NEWS.rst) it is save to assume (did not see any [PR](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/pulls)(s) for that) that they have not yet implemented the new openssl 1.1.1 [**[11 Sep 2018]**](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x3) which is introduces **major** changes.

Your only option, beside providing a PR for *aiosmtpd*, is to **downgrade** your openssl to the latest of the **1.1.0 line** which is currently [1.1.0i](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x4).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have one question: What the risk of not downgrading? The errors I get aren't clear. Does it means that old ciphers won't be able to connect to my server, or does it means my server is not well configured and must be downgraded to work with current industries ciphers implementation?

Comment: @CyrilN. You are welcome. I think the risk is too great for you to even consider using it. You are facing multiple issues here. If the changes in openssl would be only for the TLSv1.3 you may stand a chance, but the changes that were made were also around the TLSv1.2 (also other) code so the chances for you getting this work are minimal. It may appear to work but you never know where a bug may propagate. Also you have witness the peril of mismatched versions - the error messages maybe completely useless as they may show error, but something else is causing it.

Comment: Just to be clear, what you recommend is to stay with the latest version, not downgrading? The issues related to no shared cipher means the client is connecting with an old cipher and should upgrade - which would say that my new server is more secure? (just on that point of course). Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @CyrilN. What I recommend is downgrade the openssl to 1.1.0i line on the server (and keep the line updated) till the *aiosmtpd* catches up to the openssl 1.1.1 changes.  You could get unanticipated results otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I see at first that cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 cannot work because both sides using RSA certificates (I'm wondering whether client really uses his certificate for authentication or whether it's only wrongly configured in server mode).
If You run the same client script on a python working with OpenSSL 1.1.1 the servers will agree to TLSv1.3, where the cipher suites cannot be disabled anymore so are still allowed even with the set_ciphers.
I assume if You choose proper ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 or change nothing at all in that regard on Your "old" (Openssl 1.1.0) Debian 9 it will connect without issues with TLSv1.2 to the new server.

That said, the issue with the old script to determine cipher-suites on new server is also related to the fact, that the TLSv1.3 cipher suites cannot be disabled and the script expects it can disable any cipher suite for the test (that is the way it works).

There are some cipher suites that are now completely out of OpenSSLv1.1.1, but there are others that are just disabled by default (current Python only allows HIGH ciphers and no MD5/RC4 by default - and no ciphers without athentication - and of course no SSLv3 and older).
Since python 3.6 it's very simple to get the list of offered ciphers (so the broken script is not needed anymore):

```
root@somehost:~# python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:56:13)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
>>> for cipher in ctx.get_ciphers(): print(cipher['name']+' '+cipher['protocol']) if cipher['auth'] == 'auth-rsa' else None
...
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2
DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256 TLSv1.2
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA TLSv1.0
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA SSLv3
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA TLSv1.0
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA SSLv3
AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2
AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2
AES256-SHA256 TLSv1.2
AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2
AES256-SHA SSLv3
AES128-SHA SSLv3
```

So fo a TLSv1.2 connection the minimum requirement is AES128-SHA256 (without [EC]DHE KEX) or DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256/ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 / minimum OpenSSL `Version 1.0.1 Released 14-March-2012`. So not OpenSSL version supporting TLSv1.2 should be unable to connect.
In production, thought, there may be some OpenSSLv0.98 clients (at least I know some I have still to maintain - thought I have all Tools I need for production build against a newer OpenSSL). These can only talk TLSv1.0 if not the "forbidden" SSLv3. They could at least use the suites shown as SSLv3.

So there shouldn't be many clients that cannot use one of the default proposals, but still there could be some that are eigther configured for specific cipher suites that are not preferrable from todays point of view, or even older systems, less powerfull hardware, different SSL library vendor, ... So You need to find an example that is really not working to see which additional cyphersuite has to be allowed - or maybe different authentication mechanism.

For the other point in this discussion like downgrading OpenSSL, that is definitly not the way to go. There cannot be many clients that cannot connect with default setting and even less that cannot connect at all with all available settings OpenSSLv1.1.1 still offers. And if there are they need an update, definitly..

If You really wanted/needed You can compile an older OpenSSL to go in a distinct location and a Python against that older OpenSSL version. Maybe start a second server on a second port just for that clients. Or You can run a container instead for that, but You cannot downgrade the system-OpenSSL.

***The 2nd error, KRB5_S_INIT, is indeed a bug.*** It looks like a bug in python-core async module which was introduced with Python 7.3. But this error happens only if the connection is anyway unusable (so after the connection was aandoned because of the no common cipher suites case).

Comment: Nice descriptions of the openssl and cyphers.  What you left out of the equation is the *aiosmtp* which is the intermediary and does not yet support openssl 1.1.1.

Comment: @tukan You ar wrong. aiosmtp does not need to support openssl version. the ssl processing is done by pythons ssl module which do not change much with openssl 1.1.1 (if at all, besides the fact the TLS1.3 ciphers cannot be removed). it does nothing with SSL but hand through the ssl context and initiates probmotion of the connection to SSL when STARTLS command detected - nothing changes in that path with openssl version.

Comment: The ssl module indeed changes (what is "much" is rather subjective)  - to view the changes https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/529525fb5a8fd9b96ab4021311a598c77588b918 and to quote "Python has provisional and Experimental support for TLS 1.3 with OpenSSL 1.1.1.  The new protocol behaves slightly differently than previous version of TLS/SSL.  Some new TLS 1.3 features are not yet available."  Yes, it does use the SSL but if the protocol behaves differently, as written in the PR comment, you need to test it if it works correctly as intended.  There is no such test for aiosmtp.

Comment: That is for me show stopper on production.  You can have different view, but that does not mean my I'm wrong.

Comment: No thats wrong. For application that is using the socjket and the SSL module nothing changes. It just establishes connection and transfers data as before. So no module needs to take the chanages into account, as long as the do not care for setting up the context (that is exactly what the most modules not do - they leave it up to user to provide a context or may offer to create a default context as python is offering for user). @tukan

Comment: The changes are regarding exact configuration and new features of TLSv1.3, but basic stuff is working. TLSv1.3 is everywhere Experimental. It's new but production proof with the features available / the basic features. If You set up a TLSv1.3 connection in Your client it works, otherweise it would be disabled on almost all packages the vendors like redhat and suse offer. It isnt for good reason. It's easy to use (it will mostly work  out of the bix without any changes just needs recompile) for basic stuff. And it is working and more efficient and secure then TLSv1.2

Comment: you are contradicting yourself.  If something is experimental it can't be consider more secure.  It is, without a doubt, more efficient than TLSv1.2.  If it really is more secure that needs to be seen and tested; shiny new != more secure.  As for testing it, I do not agree with you.  If something so important changes it needs to be tested even when there should not be "any" changes - from my experience you never know when things go south.

Comment: They tested at the places where needed. The public SSL API just did not change so no need to test the projects that just use that API without doing any specific thing which could be different for TLSv1.3 - which most library projects do not do. Anyway one should always include a test run to latest python version in the project. On the other hand a minor ersion update can be expected to not break anything for python, so You can leve it up to users to report PRs if something changed if You have an open source product and noc commercial benefit from it.

Comment: Fot he question of secure, yes You are right we do not know, but it's unlikely that is has some new archtictural flaws. More secure is it in that regard that only few secure cipher suites are available and are to be used. That they call it experimental there is that the TLSv1.3 was not released back then. Now it's still provisional (not fully implemented) and such the state in pythin is still experimenal not final - but the protocol works and basic functionality also works. If You donÄt like: OP_NO_TLSv1_3 is Your buddy... But sticking to a self compiled old openssl with old python - no.

Comment: I agree with you in many aspects.  Yes, `OP_NO_TLSv1_3` is important feature.  What I was suggesting to the OP is to downgrade **temporarly** openssl to oldstable 1.1.0 (with the newest python) line till the issues are solved.  When the issues/bugs (python implements whole feature set) are solved he can easily move to the stable 1.1.1 openssl line.

Comment: But you cannot downgrade and cannot solve the issues when you not see them because of downgrade. And no it isn't really good to disable tls1 3. It is in production everywhere where newer software and operating systems are in production..

Comment: And: for these problems the are not related to TLSv1.3 but to the fact that some weak cipher suites have been removed by default (some completely and some You could possibly activate with allowing more insecre cipher suits vor TLS 1.0-1.2 connections). So if, I towuld first try this. But anyway some logging need to be implemented to log eigther the IPs that get the error or the IPs that connectect with weak ciphers.

Comment: I've started a new bounty since your answer is valuable too. I need to wait 24 hours before giving it but then you'll receive it.

Comment: Hope You have an idea how to log the addresses and/or the ciphers the problematic clients offer but are rejected by Your modern setup @CyrilN. . Would be happy to receive Your bounty.

Comment: No I don't really know how to catch it. The owner of the aiosmtpd repository asked me to provide a PR. I'll try to do that and try to catch the ciphers and user in the same time, but so for no. The Bounty will be awarded to you ;)

Comment: If I find time to look again maybe I have an idea how to do that. Currently I have some business tasks and private appointments on the weekend so I don't know.

Comment: So I took the time to make a PR [https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/pull/176] that improves logging. You can see then which client caused the error to clarify with sender that they need agree an some OpenSLL 1.1.1 compatible cyphers.   Sadly till not possible to get full details like which ciphers the client offers, but that is a limitation of python core.